# how to merge segmented m4s or find the init file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, segment

i have this locked video that i can watch but looking at the responses i see that the video looks like its split into 3 m4s segments

this video seems to be hosted in vimeo but i can't seem to know where to find the init.mp4 nor do i knoew how to merge the segment and turn it into mp4 with ffmpeg

[image]

hi , i have this locked video that i can watch but looking at the responses i see that the video looks like its split into 3 m4s segments

this video seems to be hosted in vimeo but i can't seem to know where to find the init.mp4 nor do i knoew how to merge the segment and turn it into mp4 with ffmpeg

[image]